Duplicate payment for Google and Apple subscriptions
I am using subscriptoin in the Google Play billing system.
We have a 7-day grace period and a 21-day account hold.
After the grace period, the user is left with no subscription. How does everyone handle this when they try to start a subscription on another platform like Apple?
Are you preventing them from getting a new subscription, or are you letting them get a new subscription and Google unsubscribes them?
